# Count and define number of inputs with specific ID prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 33 inputs with ID's ranging from 1 - 33. So for example they range from "price-1" all the way to "price-33"

Instead of individually define these elements one by one like this:

```
var p1 = document.getElementById("price-1");
var p2 = document.getElementById("price-2");
```

How can I automatically count (perhaps count by the `price-` prefix?) and define each of these elements using JavaScript (or jQuery if it's easier)?

Comment: You may be better off using a data field and loading them into an array.

Comment: Could you provide an answer with it in an array? I'd be interested to see.

Comment: @Trace - I'd really love an example of your solution.

Comment: Give me a minute to formulate an answer with motivation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) ( starts with:- `[attr^=value]`):

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value.

**Demo:** Using vanilla JS:

```js
var elList = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=price-]');
console.log(elList.length); //5

//loop throgh all the elements whose id starts with price-
var data = {};
elList.forEach(function(el){
  data[el.id] = el.value;
});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="price-1" value="100"/>
<input id="price-2" value="200"/>
<input id="price-3" value="300"/>
<input id="price-4" value="400"/>
<input id="price-5" value="500"/>
```

**OR:** Using jQuery

```js
var count = $('[id^=price-]').length;
console.log(count); //5

//loop throgh all the elements whose id starts with price-
var data = {};
$('[id^=price-]').each(function(){
  data[this.id] = this.value;
});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="price-1" value="100"/>
<input id="price-2" value="200"/>
<input id="price-3" value="300"/>
<input id="price-4" value="400"/>
<input id="price-5" value="500"/>
```

Comment: But how would I define it? I need to pass it into a Ajax data field, such as this: data: {  p1:p1, p2:p2 },

Answer (score 3):

You can use `querySelectorAll` for this purpose:

```js
// Get all elements where id starts with `price` text
const prices = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="price"]');

// Loop through each one of them
[...prices].forEach(price => {
  console.log('id: ', price.id);
  console.log('value: ', price.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="price-1" value="10" />
<input type="text" id="price-2" value="20"/>
```

Comment: But how would I define it? I need to pass it into a Ajax data field, such as this: data: {  p1:p1, p2:p2 },

Comment: @tony are you asking how to get the data into the form `{ p1:p1, p2:p2 }`?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="price-"]').forEach((el, i) => console.log(el, i))
```

Answer (score 1):

The motivation why I would prefer to use a `data` field is because I consider `id` to be a unique identifier related to the DOM element.

Your example doesn't suggest price being a unique identifier, but rather a workaround to allow crawling the DOM for price element.
Even when it would concern a unique identifier, let's say an id as primary key from a database, I would use something like `data-id`, as this more descriptively mentions that we are talking about the actual *data* rather than a DOM element's id that may or may not be just a generic description that merely focuses on uniqueness.

Because of this, it makes more sense to have a generic attribute to identify the price (this anything you want it to be semantically), and you can allocate custom data field that you want to retrieve later in your javascript code.

Without being fancy:

```
<div>
    <div data-type="price" data-price='5'>5<span>$</span></div>
    <div data-type="price" data-price='6'>6<span>$</span></div>
</div>

var prices = document.querySelectorAll("[data-type='price']");

for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    console.log('price:', prices[i].getAttribute('data-price'));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b03c7ars/